# NIST p256 Point Decompression: Finding Y-Coordinate For Base Point

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, elliptic-curve, ecdsa, ecdh

I'm trying to implement NIST P256 point compression and decompression and I keep getting the wrong y coordinate when I solve y = sqrt(x^3 + ax + b).

I figured a good test of the decompression would be to take the base point G defined by NIST(https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf, Section D.1.2.3) and use it's x coordinate to verify that the y coordinates I'm calculating are correct.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
 Public Shared Sub TestBasePoint()
    'Parameters for the curve as defined by NIST: https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf D.1.2.3
    Dim p As BigInteger = BigInteger.Pow(New BigInteger(2), 256) - BigInteger.Pow(New BigInteger(2), 224) + BigInteger.Pow(New BigInteger(2), 192) + BigInteger.Pow(New BigInteger(2), 96) - 1
    Dim a As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("3")
    Dim b As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291")

    'The base point 
    Dim Gx As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("48439561293906451759052585252797914202762949526041747995844080717082404635286") 'Gx = 6b17d1f2 e12c4247 f8bce6e5 63a440f2 77037d81 2deb33a0 f4a13945 d898c296
    Dim Gy As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("36134250956749795798585127919587881956611106672985015071877198253568414405109") 'Gy = 4fe342e2 fe1a7f9b 8ee7eb4a 7c0f9e16 2bce3357 6b315ece cbb64068 37bf51f5

    'Compute Sqrt(x^3+ax+b) to get possible values
    Dim x3 As BigInteger = BigInteger.Pow(Gx, 3) Mod p
    Dim ax As BigInteger = (a * Gx) Mod p
    Dim x3ax As BigInteger = (x3 - ax) Mod p
    Dim alpha As BigInteger = (x3ax + b) Mod p
    Dim y_solution1 As BigInteger = Sqrt(alpha) Mod p '110978579505207128328462658488647051134659543018045598806500827547749176924776
    Dim y_solution2 As BigInteger = (p - y_solution1) '4813509705149120434234788460760522395426600397244715389032803761117920929175

End Sub
```

I'm getting possible points

- **110978579505207128328462658488647051134659543018045598806500827547749176924776**
- **4813509705149120434234788460760522395426600397244715389032803761117920929175**

neither of which are the expected base y point of

- **36134250956749795798585127919587881956611106672985015071877198253568414405109**

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t just take the normal square root here, you need to take the *modular* square root. In other words, given a integer *n* and a prime *p*, you need to find the integer *r* such that *r*<sup>2</sup> ≡ *n* mod *p*.

I don’t know if VB provides a modular square root function, it doesn’t look like it does. Some languages do provide it in their standard library, e.g. [Go](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.ModSqrt).

Assuming it doesn’t have one, you will either need to find one or create your own. A start would be researching [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm).

Comment: Fortunately since his prime p is 3 mod 4 be may simple compute α ^ (p+1)/4 mod p.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Since the prime was 3 mod 4 I was able to compute  α ^ (p+1)/4 mod p. I also messed up parsing the base point from hex, so I have corrected it in the post for the sake of anyone who runs across it.